# Preload dynamic Javascript `import(modules)` with `<link/>` in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6, preload

The `<link rel="preload"></link>` HTML feature can be used to fetch scripts and static data on document load, but it doesn't seem to have any provisions for Javascript modules at all.

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content#What_types_of_content_can_be_preloaded)

A recent `<link rel="modulepreload"></link>` feature has been advertised by Google as solving this, while they also explicitly explained why `rel="preload"` wouldn't work for modules:

[developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/12/modulepreload)

Support for this feature in Firefox is unclear, but it is apparently part of the WHATWG HTML Standard:

[caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=link-rel-modulepreload)
[github.com](https://github.com/Fyrd/caniuse/pull/4998)

[developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/modulepreload)
[html.spec.whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-modulepreload)

**Can `<link rel="modulepreload></link>` be used for modules dynamically imported with calls to `import(modulepath)`?** Is this use supported both in practice and by the relevant specifications, and if not, then what is the best way to preload dynamically imported Javascript modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes, `rel="modulepreload"` should also work for dynamic `import()` calls in Javascript.** It should put the fetched modules in the JS module map that's used for all static and dynamic imports.

---

If you'd read the spec you'd linked, you'd have noticed that it specifically gives this case as an example:

> The following code shows how `modulepreload` links can be used in conjunction with `import()` to ensure network fetching is done ahead of time, so that when `import()` is called, the module is already ready (but not evaluated) in the [module map](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#module-map):
>
> ```
> <link rel="modulepreload" href="awesome-viewer.mjs">
>
> <button onclick="import('./awesome-viewer.mjs').then(m => m.view())">
>   View awesome thing
> </button>
> ```

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#example-modulepreload-dynamic-import